# Ansible merge lists based on condition

Tags: list, merge, ansible

I have two list:

```
list1:
  - file: f1
    perm: '777'
  - file: f2
    perm: '677'
  - file: f3
    perm: '755'
  - file: f4
    perm: '700'
```

```
list2:
  - file: f4
    t_perm: '755'
  - file: f3
    t_perm: '677'
  - file: f10
    t_perm: '777'
```

I have to merge them into new list as below:

```
list3:
  - file: f1
    perm: '777'
  - file: f2
    perm: '677'
  - file: f3
    perm: '755'
    t_perm: '677'
  - file: f4
    perm: '700'
    t_perm: '755'
```

Normal merging is done by

```
   - set_fact:
        list3: "{{ (list1 + list2)|
                   groupby('file')|
                   map('last')|
                   map('combine')|
                   list }}"
```

But I have one more condition. If the file is present in list1  and not in list2, then merge. If the file is present in list2 and not in list1, then dont merge, ignore that.

Comment: I have updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update.

The filter *community.general.lists_mergeby* does the job. Given the lists

```yaml
  list1:
    - {file: f1, perm: '777'}
    - {file: f2, perm: '677'}
    - {file: f3, perm: '755'}
    - {file: f4, perm: '700'}

  list2:
    - {file: f4, t_perm: '755'}
    - {file: f3, t_perm: '677'}
    - {file: f10, t_perm: '777'}
```

Q: ***"If the file is present in list2 and not in list1, then dont merge."***

A: Declare the list of files from *list1* and select them from *list2*

```yaml
  list1_files: "{{ list1|map(attribute='file')|unique }}"
  list2_select: "{{ list2|selectattr('file', 'in', list1_files) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  list1_files:
    [f1, f2, f3, f4]

  list2_select:
    - {file: f4, t_perm: '755'}
    - {file: f3, t_perm: '677'}
```

Then, merge the lists

```yaml
  list3: "{{ [list1, list2_select]|community.general.lists_mergeby('file') }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  list3:
    - {file: f1, perm: '777'}
    - {file: f2, perm: '677'}
    - {file: f3, perm: '755', t_perm: '677'}
    - {file: f4, perm: '700', t_perm: '755'}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    list1:
      - {file: f1, perm: '777'}
      - {file: f2, perm: '677'}
      - {file: f3, perm: '755'}
      - {file: f4, perm: '700'}
    list2:
      - {file: f4, t_perm: '755'}
      - {file: f3, t_perm: '677'}
      - {file: f10, t_perm: '777'}

    list1_files: "{{ list1|map(attribute='file')|unique }}"
    list2_select: "{{ list2|selectattr('file', 'in', list1_files) }}"
    list3: "{{ [list1, list2_select]|community.general.lists_mergeby('file') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: list1|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: list2|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: list1_files|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: list2_select|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: list3|to_yaml
```

---

Origin.

To meet the conditions we need to remove items from the list2 that are not in list1

1. "in list1" AND "not in list2" => merge
2. "in list2" AND "not in list1" => don't merge

For example, [intersect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory) the lists of files and get `my_keys`. Create `my_list` with files both in list1 and list2 and use it in the already tested task `set_fact`

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list3: "{{ (list1 + my_list)|
                   groupby('file')|
                   map('last')|
                   map('combine')|
                   list }}"
      vars:
        my_keys: "{{ list2|map(attribute='file')|
                     intersect(list1|map(attribute='file'))|
                     list }}"
        my_list: "{{ list2|selectattr('file', 'in', my_keys)|
                     list }}"
    - debug:
        var: list3
```

gives

```yaml
  list3:
  - file: f1
    perm: '777'
  - file: f2
    perm: '677'
  - file: f3
    perm: '755'
    t_perm: '677'
  - file: f4
    perm: '700'
    t_perm: '755'
```